# Joint Distribution applied to quadratic equations.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If i pick random number $b$ and $c$ from $[0,1]$ and then define $p(x) = x^2+bx+c$, what is the probability that p has two real roots?.

I've been thinking that it would be enough to know $P\{4c < b^2\}$, but i'm stuck there, i've been thinking about defining two random variables with uniform distribution for all the possible values of $b$ and $c$ but it doesn't seem to do any good.

Comment: Well, in the $(b,c)$ coordinate, you should find the area where $c < b^2/4,$ that is, the area below the parabola $b^2/4,$ bounded by $b=0, b=1.$ Can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting by $f_b$ the pdf of $b$, you can write 
$$
P(c < b^2/4) = \int_0^1P(c < x^2/4\ |b = x)f_b(x)dx.
$$

Now, assuming that $b$ and $c$ are uniform distributed,  $f_b(x) = x \mathbb 1_{x\in (0,1)}$ and $P(c < x) = x$, so
$$
\int_0^1P(c < x^2/4\ |b = x) x  dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{4} x  dx = \frac 1{16}.
$$